# Проблемы с RecycleView android

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

Добрый день. Возникла проблема с RecycleView, а именно:
Как-то странно забиваются данные в список, если список данных очень большой, то создаются элементы с одинаковыми данными. Как-то так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Файл /acct, /efs, /config и др повторился дважды и более.

Я подозреваю, что ошибка где-то тут, но никак не могу ее искоренить

```
 public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    // each data item is just a string in this case
    public static TextView fileName;
    public static TextView fileType;
    public static ImageView icon;
    ViewHolder(View itemView ) {
        super(itemView);
       fileName=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.file_name);
        fileType=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.file_type);
        icon=(ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    }



}

public FileManagerAdapter(LinkedList<FileData> fileData) {
    this.fileData=fileData;
}


@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.file_manager_field, parent, false);
    ViewHolder VH = new ViewHolder(v);
    return VH;
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(FileManagerAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    ViewHolder.fileName.setText(fileData.get(position).fileName);
    ViewHolder.fileType.setText(fileData.get(position).fileType);
    ViewHolder.icon.setImageResource(fileData.get(position).photoId);
    Log.e("pos", String.valueOf(position)+"      "+fileData.get(position).fileName);

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.e("clicl position", String.valueOf(position)+"       "+ fileData.size());
           MainActivity.dir=fileData.get(position).fileName;
            MainActivity.br.sendEmptyMessage(0);
        }
    });
}



@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return fileData.size();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Сделайте поля НЕ статичными

вместо `public static TextView fileName;` нужно `public TextView fileName;`

вместо `public static TextView fileType;` нужно `public TextView fileType;`

вместо `public static ImageView icon;` нужно `public ImageView icon;`

2. Поменяйте ViewHolder на holder

вместо `ViewHolder.fileName.setText(fileData.get(position).fileName);` нужно `holder.fileName.setText(fileData.get(position).fileName);`

вместо `ViewHolder.fileType.setText(fileData.get(position).fileType);` нужно `holder.fileType.setText(fileData.get(position).fileType);`

вместо `ViewHolder.icon.setImageResource(fileData.get(position).photoId);` нужно `holder.icon.setImageResource(fileData.get(position).photoId);`